# controller has no container set error after chaning directory structure

Tags: php, symfony

I start new project and install fresh copy of Symfony 5 (microservice skeleton), and add first controller `HealthCheckController`  to the default folder `src/Controller`, at this moment all is fine, I can get access to it from browser.

In next step I change a project name in `composer.json` and all related namespaces in code to

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Project\\SubProject\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Project\\SubProject\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
```

and in `service.yaml`

```
    Project\SubProject\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class

    Project\SubProject\Controller: # assuming you have namespace like that
        resource: '../src/Controller/'
        tags: [ 'controller.service_arguments' ]
```

everything still works.

Next step is to change directory structure, add layers and modules. So I move `Kernel.php` to the  `Common/Infrastructure/Symfony/` (ofcourse I change path to config files in the kernel) and controller to folder `Common/Interfaces/Controller` and change configs in the `service.yaml`

```
    Project\SubProject\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/Common/Infrastructure/Symfony/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Common/Infrastructure/Symfony/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Module1/Infrastructure/Entity/'
            - '../src/Module2/Infrastructure/Entity/'
            - '../src/Module3/Infrastructure/Entity/'
            - '../src/Module1/Test/'
            - '../src/Module2/Test/'
            - '../src/Module3/Test/'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class

    Project\SubProject\Common\Interfaces\Controller\: # assuming you have namespace like that
        resource: '../src/Common/Interfaces/Controller/'
        tags: [ 'controller.service_arguments' ]
```

and in `routes/annotation/yaml`

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Common/Interfaces/Controller
    type: annotation

kernel:
    resource: ../../src/Common/Infrastructure/Symfony/Kernel.php
    type: annotation
```

and now I'm getting error `Project\SubProject\Common\Interfaces\Controller\HealthCheckController" has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber?`

What I'm doing wrong, I forgot to change something???

I know you can tell me you need to add container to controller like  this

```
   Project\SubProject\Common\Interfaces\Controller\HealthCheckController:
        calls:
            - method: setContainer
              arguments: ['@service_container']
```

but it's stupid to configure each controller manually when autowire feature turned on, and when it worked with a default directory structure.

Also I clear cache by CLI command and manually deleting folder.

Comment: I'm honestly out of ideas. According to https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/deep-dive/controller-container , the service container should be set if your controller extends the AbstractController (which it apparently does), so the only remaining problem could have been auto-wiring, which apparently already works. So unless you have overridden and screwed up setContainer, this error shouldn't appear.

Comment: I'm sure its stupid issue, some typo or something, but I cant find it .... :)

Comment: the example where you set the service container explicitly for your healthcheckcontroller, does it work *exactly* as you posted it? because there the Controller sub namespace is missing. nevermind your error message did contain it ...

Comment: Hi, as part of a Clean Architecture and DDD case study, I seem to have encountered a similar issue. If you wish, try to exclude '../src/Common/Interfaces/Controller/' from resources in 'Project \ SubProject \'.

Comment: Can you check `bin/console debug:autowiring <ControllerName>` if the controller was correctly autowired and if the `controller.service_arguments` tag was applied? The config looks correct, but maybe that helps identify the issue. Do you have other service config files beside `services.yaml` or compiler passes in DependencyInjection that could accidentally override service definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was somewhat difficult to follow exactly what your configuration files ended as.  I don't have a specific answer for you but I was a bit intrigued at the notion of moving Kernel.php.  You did not mention moving the config directory so I chose to leave it where it was and:

```
namespace Project\SubProject\Common\Infrastructure\Symfony;
class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    protected function configureContainer(ContainerConfigurator $container): void
    {
        $base = $this->getProjectDir();
        $container->import($base . '/config/{packages}/*.yaml');
        $container->import($base . '/config/{packages}/'.$this->environment.'/*.yaml');
        $container->import($base . '/config/services.yaml');
        $container->import($base . '/config/{services}_'.$this->environment.'.yaml');
    }
        # same for configureRoutes

# project/config/services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    Project\SubProject\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/Common/Infrastructure/Symfony/Kernel.php'

    Project\SubProject\Common\Interfaces\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Common/Interfaces/Controller/'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

# project/config/routes/annotations.yaml
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Common/Interfaces/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

Tweaked index.php and console to use the new Kernel path and it all worked as expected.

I should point out that as long as you are extending from AbstractController then you don't actually need the Controller section in services.yaml at all.  It's quite puzzling why you seem to be getting a controller service but setContainer is not being called.

```
bin/console debug:container HealthCheckController
Class            Project\SubProject\Common\Interfaces\Controller\HealthCheckController  
  Tags             controller.service_arguments                                           
                   container.service_subscriber                                           
  Calls            setContainer
```

The Calls setContainer is obviously the important line.

I'm guessing you do have a typo somewhere and I suspect you did not actually start your namespace with Project\SubProject.  But again it does work as expected.

Just for my own reference I [checked in my test project](https://github.com/cerad/kernel5).

Comment: yeah, issue was in incorrect path in the Kernel, I change path for import lines but not for those if `is_file(\dirname(__DIR__).'/config/services.yaml')` , so I found that base kernel has method `getProjectDir()` which is a pass to the roor of the project and use it to build correct path.

Comment: I forgot about getProjectDir.  Good choice as long as you don't plan on moving the config directory.  Though if you look at the code the implementation is a bit screwy.  It goes up directories until it finds composer.json.  And I just deleted the is_file stuff since I knew I was not going to be using services.php or routes.php.